# how to detect 'Enter Key' in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, integer

I want to detect enter pressed to break loop.
If user press 2 enters in a row, loop breaks.
I'm using vector to store user input.
All variable's type is integer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   int buffer;
    vector<int> frag;
    do
    {
        cin >>buffer;
        frag.push_back(buffer);
    }while(frag.end()!='\n');


}
```

How can I escape from error message 
"no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::vector::iterator....."?

Comment: My goodness, not #include<buffer>, #include <vector>

Comment: Do you mean `frag.back()`?

Comment: what is "some codes" ? please provide a [mcve]. in particular, what is `frag`?

Comment: vector<int> frag;
frag is just a vector

Comment: Have a look a the following posts: [Press Enter to Contine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903221/press-enter-to-continue) and [Detect hitting Enter Key in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325932/detect-hitting-enter-key-in-c).

Comment: I did, but it didn't solve my problem. I need to compare integer versus enter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect hitting Enter Key in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325932/detect-hitting-enter-key-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Press Enter to Continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903221/press-enter-to-continue)

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `std::cin.get` against `\n`:

```
std::vector<int> vecInt;
char c;

while(std::cin.peek() != '\n'){
    std::cin.get(c);

    if(isdigit(c))
        vecInt.push_back(c - '0');
}

for (int i(0); i < vecInt.size(); i++)
    std::cout << vecInt[i] << ", ";

The input : 25uA1 45p
The output: 2, 5, 1, 4, 5,
```

- If you want to read in two integer values so after hitting Enter key for the second time it will stop reading:

  ```
  std::vector<int> vecInt;
  int iVal, nEnterPress = 0;


  while(nEnterPress != 2){

      if(std::cin.peek() == '\n'){
          nEnterPress++;
          std::cin.ignore(1, '\n');
      }
      else{
          std::cin >> iVal;
          vecInt.push_back(iVal);
      }
  }

  for (int i(0); i < vecInt.size(); i++)
      std::cout << vecInt[i] << ", ";

  Input:  435  (+ Press enter )
          3976 (+ Press enter)

  Output: 435, 3976,
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but I need integer type, not char for a vector

Comment: it only take one input.
I need multiple input until two enters.

Comment: `I need multiple input until two enters` You mean with "two" "double press" enter to stop reading or you mean until character `2` enters?